# Alternatives to Random Forest's Feature Importance for choosing best features

Tags: r, feature-selection, random-forest, importance

I have already established method using R's Random Forest [tools](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/randomForestExplainer/vignettes/randomForestExplainer.html) for
ranking most important features; for binary classification task.

I'm looking for other methods for doing the same task. So that 
I can be sure that the features selection becomes more trustable.
What are other alternatives to RF methods? (non-tree based?)

Comment: Are you asking for a catalogue of methods for assessing feature importances across all types of models?  Since there is no agreed upon principle for what a "feature importance" measurement should communicate, there are many, many possibilities, and its not within the scope of the site to breakdown all of them.

Answer (score 1):

There is an algorithm called the ReliefF algorithm that would work.

You could use Lasso regression to remove unimportant features.

Answer (score 1):

`randomForest::importance()` already offers two measures of importance:

- the reduction in out-of-bag predictive performance (measured by MSE) if a predictor is permuted randomly
- the total decrease in node impurities from splitting on the variable, averaged over all trees, measured through the Gini index

I personally would trust the first measure more, since the second is "kind of" in-sample.

My recommendation would be to look at measures similar to the first one, using other KPIs than MSE with random permutations of predictors, like proper [scoring-rules](/questions/tagged/scoring-rules), either out-of-bag or on an actual holdout sample. [(Don't use accuracy.)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/312780/1352)

Alternatively, fit other models than a random forest, e.g., a logistic regression, and assess standardized parameter estimates.